# Função "=SE" com o "até" do Excel só funciona em coluna? mas não procedi em linha

Tags: microsoft-excel

Em uma pequena tabela, inseri a função "=Se" com o ":", porém ela só funciona se eu colocar os números com suas respectivas esferas coloridas em coluna, quando eu especifico que eu quero da células =se(A23:C23=2;$D$20) o resultado não fica "aguardando", mas quando eu coloco em colunas as células "A23" até "C23" o resultado sai correto(aguardando), como eu faço para especificar em linha as célula "A23" até "C23"??[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tente inserir a fórmula com Ctrl+Shift+Enter. E não só com enter, pois ela utiliza matrizes.

Comment: Tenta da seguinte forma: `=SE(E(A23=2;B23=2;C23=2);D20)`

Answer (score 1):

Se por `=SE(A23:C23=2;$D$20)` você queira dizer: verificar se todas os valores são iguais a `2`. Então, isso vai ser sempre inválido, a não ser que a sequência seja na mesma coluna e mesmo assim só vai verificar se o `A23` é igual a `2`, ignorando todos os outros valores. Uma formula correta para isso seria `=SE(CONT.SE(A23:C23;2)=CONT.VALORES(A23:C23);$D$20)`